# Appending or adding new text next to current tooltip text JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append, jquery-tooltip

I was wondering whether its possible to add new text next to or append text to existing text already on tooltip.

For example, I have a div tag containing tooltip text like so;

```
<div id="myDiv1" class="myDiv" title="This is Tooltip">body text </div>
```

As shown above, the current tooltip text is: `This is Tooltip`

What I want to do is using jquery, appned / add more text to this. For example,

```
This is toopltip for myDiv1
```

I have tried, but these don't seem to work and most don't return anything some return undefined, please help;

```
$('#myDiv1').attr("title",  $('#myDiv1').tooltip + "" + "\nSome new text to append");
$('#myDiv1').prop("tooltipText",  $('#myDiv1').tooltipText + "" + "\nSome new text to append");
$('#myDiv1').attr("data-original-title",  $('#myDiv1').tooltipText + "" + "\nSome new text to append");
```

Any help is welcomed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do like this:

```
$('#test').attr('title', $('#test').attr('title') + '\nworld');
```

[See jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/soyuka/eLo67Lmr/1/).

I'd add that if you use a function it gives you the current element as context which can be really useful:

```
$('#test').attr('title', function() {
  console.log($(this).attr('title'));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use the `callBack` function of `.attr()` to accomplish your task,

```
$('#myDiv1').attr("title", function(_ , currentAttr){
  return currentAttr + "your text";
});
```

Comment: This seemed to do the trick, however, I am going to wait for a bit longer and see what other ways are available :) in the mean +1 and thanks.

Comment: @Henry Glad to help! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var currentVal = $('#myDiv1').attr('title');
$('#myDiv1').attr('title', currentVal + ' potatoe');
```

fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/jdz5yz6k/

Answer (score 0):

It's so simple,At first we need to get current title of this div. After that We have to append some text with this title.

Here is Jsfiddle Example

```
<div id="myDiv1" class="myDiv" title="This is Tooltip">body text </div>
```

[Then the Jquery Code is:](https://jsfiddle.net/1m5srowq/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".myDiv").hover(function(e){
    $(this).attr('title',$(this).attr('title')+"This is new text that will be added");
 });
 })
```